# Simple Make File Error

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, virtualbox

I am trying to create a simple make file and using it to build a simple c program. The environment is in virtual box using the newest version of ubuntu. I have already downloaded the linux headers for ubuntu but still getting the error.

Hello.c

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int hello_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "TEST: Hello world, this is soliducode\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "TEST: Good byte, from soliduscode");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += Hello.o

KDIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic

all: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBSIRS=$ modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

Error

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic SUBSIRS=modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:138: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:669: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:462:1: fatal error: opening dependency file scripts/basic/.fixdep.d: Permission denied
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.host:91: recipe for target 'scripts/basic/fixdep' failed
make[3]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
Makefile:449: recipe for target 'scripts_basic' failed
make[2]: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:184: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your kernel config is invalid.

There is documentation how to build your own kernel on Ubuntu, e.g.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Answer (score 0):

Try using in `M=${PWD}` option in your Makefile.

Command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=${PWD} modules
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Manish Dharanenthiran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819955/14390903) solved the problem for me.
I was on this problem for about 2 days.
compiled a new kernel, download another one from https://www.kali.org/downloads/, and still got those errors.

To help with that kind of problem I suggest the path below -

1. first check the kernel you running on with

   `uname -r`
2. check if you got your current kernel linux-headers inside `/usr/src`

   `ls -a /usr/src`

- if you don't, you need to install them **but old version of linux-headers doesn't available by apt-get** check if yours available in the list that received by

  `apt-cache search linux-headers`
- if your current version is there jump to 3.
- if your current version doesn't available you need to: apt-get update & apt-get upgrade / install a newer machine / compile a new kernel

NOTICE - from my experience (I did them all) the update & upgrade is the fastest.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
reboot
```

**When booting choose the new kernel in the grub menu**

**You can edit [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLZs0.png) with bigger GRUB_TIMEOUT value if you can't see/catch the menu in boot time**

---

3. Download the needed linux-headers

   `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
4. If the problem didn't solve yet, try using in `M=${PWD}` instead of `M=$(PWD)` in your Makefile as mentioned by [@Manish Dharanenthiran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819955/14390903).