# include/config/auto.conf.cmd : No such file or directory [Kali Linux]

Tags: linux, makefile, adapter, wifi, kali-linux

Good afternoon, 
I want to compile the driver for my TL-WN821N V6 in Kali Linux. I have finished the instructions so far that I have installed the Linux header. The header is in the version linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-amd64. The next step is to compile the driver source, which is done by executing the command make in the folder.  But when I do that I get this error:

```
kali@kali:~$ cd /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-amd64/
kali@kali:/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-amd64$ sudo make
sh: 0: Can't open /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-common/scripts/mkmakefile
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-common/Makefile:513: outputmakefile] Error 127
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-common/Makefile:659: include/config/auto.conf.cmd: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-common/Makefile:677: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali3-common/Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
```

So far I found out, as mentioned in the title, that the `include/config/auto.conf.cmd` is missing. Hope you can help me.
I am new to Linux, so forgive me if it is a trivial mistake.

Comment: How does your makefile look like? Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66240308/14390903) can help you

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install packages from the list below:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential flex bison libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

and then:

```
make config
```